# Specifying output file from inside a RMarkdown document

Tags: r, jekyll, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to use RMarkdown to write posts about R for my blog (that uses Jekyll). Quite smooth except for one minor annoyance: I can't find a way to specify the output file inside the `.Rmd` document. By default, the output has the same name as the original document, only with a `.md` extension. I don't want to use the same name for both files because I follow the Jekyll convention of prefixing the `.md` files with the date, something that's not always necessary for the `.Rmd`s.

I tried using the `output_file` argument on the front matter, but it didn't work. My hope is that there's a subtle way of passing parameters to `rmarkdown::render` from inside the document.

Here's a sample YAML front matter (does not work):

```
---
output:
  md_document:
    output_file: "2017-05-19-computacao-simbolica-R-2-4.md"
    variant: markdown_github
  html_document: null
---
```

Comment: What's the problem of writing your .Rmd file and then running `rmarkdown::render('my_jekyll.Rmd', output_file = "2017-05-19-computacao-simbolica-R-2-4.md")` on the R console?

Comment: Convenience :) notice that the shortcut key is always the same, while the code is not

Comment: Of course it's not something reeeally important, but since it's something so trivial I thought maybe the Rmarkdown guys already did it, just did not leave explicit documentation.